# Let $A$ a Lebesgue measurable and its measure is 0, prove the Lebesgue measure of $A^2 = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $A$ is bounded with $m(A)=0$. ($m$ is lebesgue measear). Set $E =\{x^2:x \in A \}$.

Prove $E$ is measurable and its measure is $0$.

Comment: Hint: let $I \subset [-B,B]$ be an open interval, for $B > 0$. Show that $m(I^2) \leq 2Bm(I)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $((a_n,b_n))_{n\geqslant 0}$ such that $A\subset\bigcup_{n\geqslant 0}(a_n-b_n)$, the $(a_n,b_n)$ are pairwise disjoint and $\sum_{n\geqslant 0}(b_n-a_n)\leqslant\varepsilon$. Let $n\geqslant 0$, if $a_n\geqslant 0$ then $(a_n,b_n)^2=(a_n^2,b_n^2)$, if $b_n\leqslant 0$ then $(a_n,b_n)^2=(b_n^2,a_n^2)$ and if $a_n b_n\leqslant 0$, then $(a_n,b_n)^2=(0,\max(a_n^2,b_n^2))$. But $A^2\subset\bigcup_{n\geqslant 0}(a_n,b_n)^2$ and there is at most one $n$ such that $a_nb_n\leqslant 0$, if such a $n$ exists then $m((a_n,b_n)^2)=\max(a_n^2,b_n^2)=\max(|a_n|,|b_n|)^2\leqslant (b_n-a_n)^2\leqslant\varepsilon^2$. Thus if $M>0$ is such that $A\subset[-M,M]$, then $|a_n+b_n|\leqslant 2M$ for all $n$ and
$$ \sum_{n\geqslant 0}m((a_n,b_n)^2)\leqslant \varepsilon^2+\sum_{\substack{n\geqslant 0}}|b_n^2-a_n^2|\leqslant \varepsilon^2+2M\sum_{n\geqslant 0}(b_n-a_n)\leqslant(\varepsilon+2M)\varepsilon $$
Thus $m(A^2)=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nice solution!